# Intersection of two lines - Have I got it right?

Tags: geometry

I have been asked to solve where these two lines intersect, it has been a very long time since I have done this, my numbers seem too big. Can someone check these for me?

```
2x + y = 6
x + 2y = 12

    (find x)                          (plug into first equation)
    x + 2y = 12                       2(-2y+12)+y=6
    x = -2y + 12                      -4y+24+y=6
                                      -3y=6-24
                                      -3y=18
                                       3y=18
                                       y=18-3
                                       y=15

    (put y back in)
    x=-2(15)+12
    x=-30+12
    x=-18

Intersection at (-18,15)
```

Comment: You can verify this by plugging in your solution to the two equations and check they are both equal.

Comment: By inspection, the RHS are proportional to the coefficients of $y$, hence $x=0,y=6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is wrong, try plugging them in to both equations:
$$\begin{cases} 2\times (-18)+15 \neq 6 \\-18+2\times (15)=12 \end{cases}$$
One of the equations in the system of equations is not true, therefore you've made a mistake somewhere.

---

You've made a mistake on this step:
$$3y=18 \not\Rightarrow y=18-3$$
Instead, divide $3$ by both sides to obtain:
$$3y=18 \implies \frac{3y}{3}=\frac{18}{3}\implies y=6$$
Now, try solving for $x$.

---

Apart from that, there is no mistake.

Comment: Of course, of course! I find these things very easy to make a mistake with, will try again with a fresh head :D

Answer (score 1):

**By elimination**:

$$\begin{cases}2x + y = 6,\\
    x + 2y = 12.\end{cases}$$

Subtract twice the first equation from the second and get

$$-3x=0.$$

---

**By substitution**:

From the first equation, $y=6-2x$, and plugging in the second, $x+12-4x=12$, giving $$-3x=0.$$

---

**By Cramer**:

$$x=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}6&1\\12&2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{vmatrix}}=0.$$

---

In all three cases, $y=6$ by the first equation.